# Can't store and crop image android

Tags: android, image, camera, save

I am trying to store image and crop it after save but I have one of the biggest problem ever, that problem is when I store image all things is good but when I send the URI to result the crop class opens but it's empty **NO IMAGE**
I think it gets null because the image isn't saved successfully so it get null, so I think the solution is that wait until the image save then open crop class, here's my code below:

```
Capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            mCamera.setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] picture) {

                    Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);
                    final Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 1200, 1200,false);
                    new Thread(new Runnable(){@Override public void run() {storeImage(resizedbitmap);}}).start();

                    if (getOutputMediaFile()!=null){
                        final Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getOutputMediaFile().getPath()));
                        Intent var6 = new Intent();
                        var6.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mUri);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,var6);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });

            mCamera.captureImage();}}); 

private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

    if (pictureFile == null) {runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {Toast.makeText(camera_fragment.this,R.string.error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}});return;}

    try {if (getOutputMediaFile()!=null && getOutputMediaFile().exists()){
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile.toString());
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();}}
    catch (IOException e) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override public void run() {Toast.makeText(camera_fragment.this,R.string.error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}});}
}

private File getOutputMediaFile(){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/Test/");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {Toast.makeText(camera_fragment.this,R.string.error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            });

            return null;}}

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss",Locale.US).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    String mImageName=timeStamp +".png";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile)));
    return mediaFile;
}
```

I also used Handler to wait for 3 sec and I used TimerTask and all method's but nothing work for me till now.

So please I need a solution for this problem please brothers.

Note: I'am using **CAMERAKIT LIBRARAY & UCROP LIBRRARY**.

I can't see anything in logcat, here's what I have:

```html
08-13 11:57:00.224 21808-21848/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3756
08-13 11:57:00.227 21808-21848/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 522689769
08-13 11:57:00.230 21808-21848/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=3756, _sc=camera_fragment, _si=8399813092086441151}]
08-13 11:57:00.282 21808-21848/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 522689814
08-13 11:57:00.301 21808-21852/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Fail to change FontRenderer cache size, it already initialized
08-13 11:57:00.304 21808-21848/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 36
08-13 11:57:00.308 21808-21848/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 522689849
08-13 11:57:00.374 21808-21808/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 V/FA: onActivityCreated
08-13 11:57:00.420 21808-21808/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 D/BitmapLoadUtils: maxBitmapSize: 2078
08-13 11:57:00.424 21808-21848/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 522689969
08-13 11:57:00.425 21808-21852/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Fail to change FontRenderer cache size, it already initialized
08-13 11:57:00.444 21808-22211/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 D/BitmapWorkerTask: Uri scheme: file
08-13 11:57:00.460 21808-22211/com.pcsoftgroup.beta1 D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
```

Comment: Please print **mediaStorageDir.getPath()** after `mImageName = timeStamp + ".png"`. You will get some hint here.

Comment: Ok I will try it now.

Comment: Yes sure do it.

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: Sorry brother but couldn't go any solution.

Comment: Please print **mediaStorageDir.getPath()** and comment here.

Comment: Ok, just wait a little while.

Comment: I used System.out.printf(mediaStorageDir.getPath()); but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: System.out.printf("printingPath"+mediaStorageDir.getPath());  Now search for printingPath in your logcat

Comment: see the new update in my question.

Comment: Change  `File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/Test/")`

to
   `File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Pictures/Test/")`

Comment: It doesn't work the / should be at the beginning.